# Send mail with attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Edit**: **I'm able to send mail without attachment**

Getting this error while trying to send mail:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out.
```

Following is my code:

```
public static void SendMailMessage(string to, string subject, string body, List<string> attachment)
{
    MailMessage mMailMessage = new MailMessage();
    // string body; --> Compile time error, body is already defined as an argument

    mMailMessage.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com");

    mMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));

    mMailMessage.Subject = subject;

    mMailMessage.Body = body;

    foreach (string s in attachment)
    {
        var att = new Attachment(s);

        mMailMessage.Attachments.Add(att);

    }


    // Set the format of the mail message body as HTML
    mMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    // Set the priority of the mail message to normal
    mMailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;

    using (SmtpClient mSmtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage);
    }
}
```

Web Config

```
 <system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="mailid">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" enableSsl="true" userName="username" password="pass" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Note : Attachments not exceeding its limit(below than 25 mb)

What can I do to solve this problem, or what am I missing?

Comment: timeout probably indicates a failure to connect to the mail server.

Comment: It's unlikely that the gmail smtp is offline, so try setting enableSsl to false and test. I believe they use TLS instead of SSL for sending

Comment: Ok apparently you should indeed set ssl to true, have you tried opening a raw session to the SMTP from the PC you are running the software on?

Comment: Does it work if you don't include the attachment?

Comment: There is one error in your code sample though, you defined "body" twice. Once as an argument and once as a local var, normally this will not compile

Comment: @TimothyP The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated when setted enableSsl=false, plus im able to send mail without attachment(link of files(href to my hosting server) with body), but i want to attach files with mail if they are below than gmail limit, defined "body" twice is actual code, posted by mistake, btw thanks for pointing out

Comment: @SizS ok, in that case you should update your question to indicate that you are indeed able to send without attachment that sheds a whole new light on the problem sorry for the confusion

Comment: @SizS is ati-erp.com a Google Apps domain? Because you will not be able to send email from ati-erp.com with a normal gmail account unless ... you set that sender address up as an alias in your gmail account configuration... this just hit me

Comment: @TimothyP yeah its Google Apps domain, and updated it with abc@gmail.com, it will more clear now

Comment: ok just checking so we can eliminate all possibilities, I'm trying to run the code on my machine now

Comment: @TimothyP very nice of you +1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25699/discussion-between-timothyp-and-siz-s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically we discovered during the chat that the problem occurs
because the upload of the attachments takes to long.

One way to solve it is to increase the timeout value of the SmtpClient:

```
mSmtpClient.Timeout = int.MaxValue;
```

Note: Use int.MaxValue for testing but use a more realistic value for the deployed solution.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a local smtp server to relay through, or use something like http://aws.amazon.com/ses/.  I don't think google is going to allow you to programtically relay through their servers.

Comment: They do, the domain you are sending from resolves to the computer you are sending from. In fact I just opened up a raw putty session to 587, they allow me to connect without any issues. The SMTP protocol does not provide google with the means to see which program you are using to connect to it and a realy smtp server is just another program. We do it all the time